# Divs floating left in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i float left the social icons with bootstrap, with text centered?

Im showing an image here, what i want. Now i use col-md-3 divs for floating, but there are to many free spaces between the divs.

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-12 footer_social_divs_box">

    <div class="col-md-3 footer_social_divs text-center">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Ferrari/?hc_ref=NEWSFEED&fref=nf" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
             </div><div class="col-md-3 footer_social_divs text-center">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/maldives" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
             </div><div class="col-md-3 footer_social_divs text-center">
                <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuKPYzX_LZicuVA0BsYDxeg" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
             </div><div class="col-md-3 footer_social_divs text-center">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/maldives/" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
             </div>        


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't need to use the `responsive` classes on this:

```css
.footer-responsive {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 footer_social_divs_box text-center">
  <div class="footer-responsive footer_social_divs text-center">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Ferrari/?hc_ref=NEWSFEED&fref=nf" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-responsive footer_social_divs text-center">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/maldives" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-responsive footer_social_divs text-center">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuKPYzX_LZicuVA0BsYDxeg" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-responsive footer_social_divs text-center">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/maldives/" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need responsive class for that, you can simple use a padding or margin.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/leonardoaraujocosta/f070qpfh/

```
<div class="col-md-12 footer_social_divs_box">
  <div class="social_links_container">
    <div class="social_link_item">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Ferrari/?hc_ref=NEWSFEED&fref=nf" title="Facebook" target="_blank">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-superscript" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="social_link_item">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Ferrari/?hc_ref=NEWSFEED&fref=nf" title="Facebook" target="_blank">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-superscript" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="social_link_item">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Ferrari/?hc_ref=NEWSFEED&fref=nf" title="Facebook" target="_blank">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-superscript" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.social_links_container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.social_link_item {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I hope I helped you